# Rufus turned my USB into a DVD device

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I have recently used rufus to make my usb bootable and it worked as expected. Somehow it has changed my usb into a DVD drive and now it has a write protection that I don't know how to take it off to continue using my usb device. My intention was it only to make it bootable, not to convert my usb drive into a virtual dvd device. Here is what happened:

[image]

BD-ROM is the Windows DVD that rufus turned my USB and the removable Disk (G) is also my USB. Both of them I can't format or do anything. Has it damaged permanently So What can I do to turn my USB drive that is now a DVD back to a USB Drive? It doesn't allow me to format saying that "disk is write protected".

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this'll work but its worth a shot,
from within cmd, open diskpart by simply typing

```
diskpart
```

once in diskpart (looks like cmd) type

```
list disk
```

and choose the correct device, your usb, by typing

```
select disk3
```

(3 is just an example)
next type (warning this will erase the usb)

```
clean
```

once done you can exit the program

```
exit
```

now go in the start menu and search for the partition manager by typing in 'partitions'
and once opened, scroll to your usb, right click, and seelect create partiton, skip through the wizard,and then close everything.
run rufus and try to install the iso file to your usb again.

hope this works,
Jay

Comment: also, when you reuse rufus, make sure it formats as NTFS(because its widely used) and not UDF